# Compiling library with cuda 7.0 using nvcc on windows while linking to 32-bit python 2.5

Tags: python, windows, cuda, nvcc

I'm trying to compile a library that can be called from python using nvcc.  Typically on windows I use the msys/mingw toolchain and can compile python extensions with no problem.  However, when I try to compile using nvcc I believe it is using the link.exe which is (part of Microsoft Visual Studio).  Although it compiles just fine, it fails at the link step.

I realize I'm using an old version of python (version 2.5).  I'm working with a legacy application and I am stuck on with the old version for the time being.

Here's the nvcc command that I'm trying:

```
nvcc -I "C:\Python25\include" -I "C:\python25\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy" -L "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v7.0\lib\x64" -lcusolver -lcusparse -Xlinker "C:\Python25\libs\python25.lib" cusolve5.cu
```

But it fails with this message:

```
   Creating library a.lib and object a.exp
tmpxft_00001128_00000000-28_cusolve5.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_PyObject_GetAttrString referenced in function _import_array
tmpxft_00001128_00000000-28_cusolve5.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_PyCObject_AsVoidPtr referenced in function _import_array
tmpxft_00001128_00000000-28_cusolve5.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_PyErr_SetString referenced in function _import_array
tmpxft_00001128_00000000-28_cusolve5.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_PyErr_Format referenced in function _import_array
tmpxft_00001128_00000000-28_cusolve5.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_PyArg_ParseTuple referenced in function main
tmpxft_00001128_00000000-28_cusolve5.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_Py_BuildValue referenced in function main
tmpxft_00001128_00000000-28_cusolve5.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_Py_InitModule4_64 referenced in function "void __cdecl initbmc(void)" (?initbmc@@YAXXZ)
tmpxft_00001128_00000000-28_cusolve5.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_PyErr_Print referenced in function "void __cdecl initbmc(void)" (?initbmc@@YAXXZ)
tmpxft_00001128_00000000-28_cusolve5.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_PyImport_ImportModule referenced in function _import_array
tmpxft_00001128_00000000-28_cusolve5.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_PyCObject_Type referenced in function _import_array
tmpxft_00001128_00000000-28_cusolve5.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_PyExc_AttributeError referenced in function _import_array
tmpxft_00001128_00000000-28_cusolve5.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_PyExc_ImportError referenced in function _import_array
tmpxft_00001128_00000000-28_cusolve5.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_PyExc_RuntimeError referenced in function _import_array
a.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 13 unresolved externals
```

It appears to me that can't find the python library.  With msys/mingw I can link a similar library like this:

```
g++ bmc.o -L "/c/python25/libs" -lpython25 -shared -o bmc.pyd
```

which works fine (but doesn't include any of the GPU acceleration I'm working on).  My guess is there's some option I need to pass link.exe through the -Xlinker command, but I can't seem to find a way to include the python library while building.

Comment: Has your Python been built with Visual Studio?

Comment: I am using an official python interpreter and libraries downloaded as a binary from python.org.  I would assume the official python distribution is compiled with Visual Studio, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: What happens if you try compiling with the visual compiler from the command line? My main point is that I don't think that you can mix compilers (and CUDA requires visual studio).

Comment: What's this all about: `-Xlinker "C:\Python25\libs\python25.lib"`  Are you trying to add that library to the link specification?  If so, that's not how you do it.  Try replacing that with `-L"C:\Python25\libs" -lpython25`  Furthermore, the `nvcc` compile command you have shown would be correct for building an executable out of `cusolve5.cu` but not correct if you are intending to build a *library*.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to hints from @talonmies, I've concluded that what I'm trying to do is impossible for 2 reasons:

1. python2.5 was compiled with VS 2005, which I don't have access to and probably isn't supported by nVidia (http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-microsoft-windows does not include such an old compiler on its list)

This could be resolved, though, by using ctypes to load the dll rather than a standard python import.  However...

2. My python binary is 32-bit and Cuda 7.0 only supports 64-bit.  The cusolver.lib and cusparse.lib (essential to my optimizations) can be found in the x64 directory of the Cuda 7.0 distribution.  Linking to them while passing  the "--machine 32" to nvcc does not work, although that is not very surprising.